# Rewrite a URL to remove the % if it's the last character in the URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to remove a % character if it is the last character in a URL?

I would like to redirect something like:
http://www.mydom.com/foo% to http://www.mydom.com/foo

I've already taken some steps to ensure no URLs are generated from my system that end that way, but we want to account for any that already were bookmarked or indexed with the ending % character.

Comment: should be something like 
RewriteRule ^(.*?)%$ http://www.mydom.com/$1

Comment: `http://www.mydom.com/foo%` is considered a BAD request by Apache hence none of the rewrite rules will work for this.

Comment: That's what I am finding as well.... it never makes it to the rules.  I'll have to dig around a little more.

Answer (score 1):

Should be as simple as:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*)%$ $1 [R,L]
```

- `(.*)` will capture anything as long as the last character is a `%`
- `$1` will contain the contents of `(.*)` and can be used as the URL to rewrite to