# Removing a character from a redirect URL in htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url, redirect, http-status-code-301

When I re-did my web site years ago, some old straggler pages were left in the old format.  So I wrote redirects in the htaccess to send them to new the pages.  Problem is the old url's added a character to the end of the main variable that I no longer use anymore.  How would I go about removing that character, it's either an "r" or a "p?"  Here's an example of one of my redirect's.

```
RedirectMatch 301 /season-stats-regular-season-(.*)\.html https://www.lakerstats.com/season-stats/?seasonid=$1
```

So it redirects the page:

```
https://www.lakerstats.com/season-stats-regular-season-5960r.html
```

to:

```
https://www.lakerstats.com/season-stats/?seasonid=5960r
```

Problem is, I need that "r" removed, so that it goes to:

```
https://www.lakerstats.com/season-stats/?seasonid=5960
```

What can I write to remove that "r" in the redirect code?  It could also be a "p" as well as I said.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28280478/rewrite-a-url-to-remove-the-if-its-the-last-character-in-the-url

Comment: Tried that, got a redirection error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/season-stats-regular-season-(.+)r\.html$ /season-stats/?seasonid=$1
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.